# Sharepoint 2013 - Custom Display Form not displaying correctly SPD

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, custom-form, people-picker

I have created many custom forms using SPD. I have come up against a problem with this current one - I need to create a custom display form for a client - it has several people lookups. I have never had a problem before so I am hoping someone else has had the issue. As long as I use the default I receive an output which looks like this:

[image]

If I create a new custom display form - without any modification to the form I receive this:

[image]

Has anyone had this issue - if so - do you have a solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I have discovered the problem I needed to include

To Display content from Rich textbox or enhanced Rich textbox, need to use below property

> disable-output-escaping="yes"

to the end of the

> xsl:value-of

This makes sense and has resolved the issue.